# What are the Documents and Documents Frames counts in Chrome Dev Tools' performance panel?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, browser, frontend

[The Documents count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IcJ3.png)

When you do a record with the 'memory' options checked in the performance panel, then check out the result. There will be a 'Documents' count near JS Heap usage and DOM Nodes count.
I don't know what it is and sometimes the count varies on the exact same webpage.
I tried to test with a blank html page and it somehow seems to have 5 documents in it.
I did some research and the explanations were literally saying that there are some 'Documents' in the page.